# What equivalent C# code for DecryptByPassPhrase or vice versa

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I have a requirement to decrypt a value on the SQL Server side which is encrypted via C#. In SQL I am using DecryptByPassPhrase for decryption.

What is the equivalent C# code for DecryptByPassPhrase or vice versa.

Thank you.

Comment: How was the value encrypted? That is what kind of encryption scheme/algorithm was used? (Think symmetric, asymmetric encryption type, specific encryption algorithms, such as AES, BlowFish).  With answers to these question, you can then find out how to decrypt the value given the encryption method.

After that you can find out if there are utilities or tools available on the platform you are trying to perform the decryption, in your case, it looks to be some sql language.

Comment: Appending to @Yiling's comment: it is always a good idea to add some sample dataset (plaintext, key, ciphertext) [from the encrypting platform] to your question to test that decryption on other platform works correctly. Last but not least: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service so kindly add the code you have written so far and you are struggling with, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr In this case I think trying to get to the protocol specification should be step 1. It seems missing from the Microsoft documentation (but hey, nothing new **there**). Please do complain about it on the Microsoft site.

Comment: _Encrypt data with a passphrase using the TRIPLE DES algorithm with a 128 key bit length_ in the [EncryptByPassPhrase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql) documentation seems pretty concise.